# Background music and sounds

Tags: c++, audio, visual-studio-2015, playsound

```
PlaySound("./backgrounMusic.wav", NULL, SND_ASYNC ) //this is my main music for my game
PlaySound("./buttonEffect.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
```

I am developing a videogame using C++ and OpenGL and Visual Studio 2015, I am trying to play a background music in a menu, but I am having problems because also I have a sound effect when I press a button but the problem is that when I press a button, the sound effect of the button stops my background music ("backgrounMusic.wav").

Is there a way to prevent this? I want that the background music keeps playing although a button is pressed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37357872/7852751 Does this help you? Also, check out the entire thread.

Answer (score 0):

Not with `PlaySound` (it is not meant to be used for mixing sounds), either use the multimedia APIs or [DirectSound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb318770%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Or perhaps a not-native library as [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look.