# Is it possible 2 mediaplayers play songs at the same time?

Tags: delphi, time, media-player

I have 2 mediaplayers in my program. The first one, plays a music. I use mediaplayer2 to add sound effects, for example when you move the cursor on a button:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
  var mouseup:string;
begin
mouseup:=extractfilepath(paramstr(0))+'Sound Effects\Mouseupbutton.mp3';

mediaplayer2.FileName:=mouseup;
mediaplayer2.Open;
mediaplayer2.Start;
```

I tested it and it is working, when there is only 1 mediaplayer....What should i do? Thank you

Comment: It seems you're going to play samples. I wouldn't personally use `TMediaPlayer` for this. I would rather recommend e.g. [`Bass.dll`](http://www.un4seen.com/) library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563974/how-to-play-multiple-wav-files-simultaneously-in-delphi

Comment: Ok, why not, so there isn't any way to do the same using mediaplayers?

Comment: The `TMediaPlayer` is a GUI control, so you should never use it unless you need its GUI. You don't want its GUI, so you shouldn't use it.

Comment: The code in the snippet will restart `Mouseupbutton.mp3` everytime you move the cursor a pixel above the form! That is almost certainly not what you want!

Comment: ok, so tell me what should i do?

Comment: no, it does not, i tested it, it waits until the song is completed

Comment: @user2296565: One solution is to use `PlaySound` in threads. It is actually easy, and all the details are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3564858/282848). Or you could follow TLama's advice and use `Bass.dll`. You could also obtain the waveform data, superpose the sounds, and send the new wave directly to the speakers, as we almost do [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456748/what-is-the-simpliest-way-to-play-sound-from-array-data-in-delphi/3462724#3462724).